# C++ application crashes while instantiating an ofstream object.

Tags: c++, ofstream, interix, pgi

I have a very irritating issue while running a C++ application. I am using the pgcpp compiler on the Interix subsystem of Windows Xp. My problem is essentially described here:

I have a class definition in a header file. This header file is included in one source file. This class has two constructors and is basically used to implement a logger. The first constructor takes ostream *out as an argument, while the second overloaded constructor takes a filename and a default boolean value of false. The objective of this second constructor is to get a stream for the filename that we are passing and to start logging messages to it. The code in the constructors is as follows:

```
MessageLogger::MessageLogger(std::ostream *out): p_out (out), p_ofstream (0)  
{  
    if (p_out)  
    {  
        (*p_out) << "Started logging messages" << endl;  
    }  
}  

MessageLogger::MessageLogger (char const *filename, bool append_to_file) : p_out (0),   p_ofstream (0)  
{  
    if (append_to_file)  
    {  
    p_ofstream = new std::ofstream (filename, ios::app);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        p_ofstream = new std::ofstream (filename);  
    }  

    p_out = p_ofstream;  

    if (p_out)  
    {  
        (*p_out) << "Started logging messages" << endl;  
    }  
}
```

Where the declarations of p_out and p_ofstream are as follows:

```
std::ostream *p_out;
std::ofstream *p_ofstream;
unsigned int p_indent_level;
```

All the three mentioned above are private members. The instantiation of the MessageLogger class is done as:

```
MessageLogger logger ("filename");
```

Please note that append_to_file has a default value of false. `PGDBG` is also misbehaving. I am inexplicably able to step in when the control is at      `p_ofstream = new std::ofstream (filename);` and it steps into a random location and then the application crashes.

Also, when I try to see either of Mixed or Disassembly code in PGDBG, the debugger crashes with the message:

```
jpgdbg parse: Newline must follow cmd in 'eleq "0" struct MessageLogger *Mes
sageLogger::MessageLogger(struct basic_ostream *out); (TranslatorGeneric.cpp
)
'
jpgdbg jpgdbgFileSelector processMsg: Warning unexpected msg token 5
jpgdbg parse: Newline must follow cmd in 'eleq "1" struct MessageLogger *Mes
sageLogger::MessageLogger(char *filename, unsigned char append_to_file); (Tr
anslatorGeneric.cpp)
'
jpgdbg jpgdbgFileSelector processMsg: Warning unexpected msg token 5
```

I am unable to reproduce this in a sample program where I did the exact same thing as above but everything works fine. Can someone please explain what is happening and if there is a fix to this?

Thanks, 
Aditya.

Comment: In your code, `append_to_file` does not have a default value.

Comment: Is your question about the application or the debugger? In both cases: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: The question is about the application which is failing. The debugger is just an added issue that I have which I thought I should share. The append_to_file is set to false. I am sorry I havent shown the entire code.

Comment: If this helps: I am inexplicably being able to step into the line  p_ofstream = new std::ofstream (filename); My debugger takes me to some random place (the same place all the time) and then to another place upon a further step in. This seems very very odd. Can there be a chance of the object file somehow getting corrupt after the compilation is complete?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using a dynamically allocated instance of ofstream? Why don't you do something like the following...

```
class Logger
{
  public:
    Logger(ostream& str) : _str(str.rdbuf()) // use the buffer from the stream
    {
      _str << "writing to passed in buffer" << endl;
    }
    Logger(const char* fname, bool append = false) : _str(cout.rdbuf())
    {
      _file.open(fname, (append)? ios::out|ios::app : ios::out);
      if (_file.is_open())
        _str.rdbuf(&_file); // redirects to file, else remains on cout

      _str << "expected to be logging to: " << fname << endl;
    }

    // use as needed

  private:
    filebuf _file;
    ostream _str;
};
```

This way even if your file fails, you'll still have the log output going to cout...

Back to your problem, what does HW_NEW do? It's kind of hard to say really with the basic information you've provided...

Comment: This is part of a huge application that I am trying to migrate to Windows. So I really do not have control or a choice as to how to do this. I have edited my question to make things slightly clear. Thanks a ton for the reply. Can you look at it now and tell me why this is failing? The sample code I was talking about was also compiled using pgcpp and hence I do not think this is a compiler issue. Unless I am wrong?

Comment: okay, go back to the beginning, have you built all the objects/libraries correctly (i.e. are they all using the correct headers etc.)? You can have random crashes if there are objects compiled with different versions of the same header file etc. As a first step, I would clean and re-compile everything. Once that's done, confirm that this is indeed where the crash happens (with a debug enabled build). Then try it in the debugger, the code above should be okay, and it could be co-incidental that the crash happens there...

Comment: I had a colleague build this whole application. The same thing happens with her. We did a fresh build. Can you tell me if you see some C++/compiler related failures that might happen? Or is this simply something that has gone kaput in the middle - if anything like that is possible.